# Create ConstraintLayout with 2 buttons and EditText fails programatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to re-create a screen from XML to code for some reason. This is what I want my screen to look like:

[image]

So pretty simple:

- Two buttons on each side (should actually be images but it's fine for now)
- EditText in the middle
- When the `EditText` grows to multiple lines, the buttons should 'stick' to the top of the `EditText`

With my code, my screen looks like this:

[image]

And I have no idea what that is the case. This is my code:

```
@Composable
fun ShowWrapped() {
    AndroidView(factory = { context ->
        createChat(context)
    })
}

fun createChat(context: Context): ConstraintLayout {
    val constraintLayout = ConstraintLayout(context).apply {
        id = View.generateViewId()
        layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            MATCH_PARENT,
            MATCH_PARENT,
        )
    }
    val buttonA = ImageButton(context).apply {
        id = View.generateViewId()
        layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            WRAP_CONTENT,
            WRAP_CONTENT,
        )
    }
    val buttonB = ImageButton(context).apply {
        id = View.generateViewId()
        layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            WRAP_CONTENT,
            WRAP_CONTENT,
        )
    }
    val editText = EditText(context).apply {
        id = View.generateViewId()
        layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            WRAP_CONTENT,
            WRAP_CONTENT,
        )
    }

    constraintLayout.addView(buttonA)
    constraintLayout.addView(buttonB)
    constraintLayout.addView(editText)

    buttonA.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
    buttonB.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)

    val set = ConstraintSet()

    set.clone(constraintLayout)

    set.connect(buttonA.id, ConstraintSet.START, constraintLayout.id, ConstraintSet.START)
    set.connect(buttonB.id, ConstraintSet.END, constraintLayout.id, ConstraintSet.END)
    set.connect(editText.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, constraintLayout.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
    set.connect(buttonA.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, editText.id, ConstraintSet.TOP)
    set.connect(buttonB.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, editText.id, ConstraintSet.TOP)
    set.connect(buttonA.id, ConstraintSet.END, editText.id, ConstraintSet.START)
    set.connect(buttonB.id, ConstraintSet.START, editText.id, ConstraintSet.END)

    set.applyTo(constraintLayout)

    return constraintLayout
}
```

Comment: First of all, use `ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID` instead of `constraintLayout.id`

Comment: @Remc4 I tried it, didn't make any difference

Comment: You are mixing composables and the traditional view system - maybe you aren't addressing all of the [concerns](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/migrate/interoperability-apis) with mixing these two systems? I would consider using [ConstraintLayout in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/constraintlayout) to make the layout.

Comment: @Cheticamp I have an extremely basic setup, I could not imagine this will not work because of different systems

Comment: Oh, I could imagine it. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *EditText* is not constrained properly. You will need to add start and end constraints to center it in the layout. (This is the gist of Remc4's answer and the core of your issue.)

```
set.connect(editText.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
set.connect(editText.id, ConstraintSet.START,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START)
set.connect(editText.id, ConstraintSet.END,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END)
```

This will position your views in the right positions. You may have additional work such as introducing a horizontal chain to make sure everything stays aligned if the *EditText* grows enough to push the buttons off the screen.

You did not post your working XML, so I can't comment on any differences between the XML and your code.

Comment: Thanks, I just have 1 more question: Do I always need to add 2 way constraints? I mean the EditTest view already was connected by buttonA and B, why didn't it work?

Comment: Each view has to be constrained vertically and horizontally, otherwise, where should it be placed? The buttons were constrained horizontally by the _EditText_ wasn't.

Comment: The constraints don't always have to be two-way. One horizontal and one vertical constraint will do. Applying two horizontal constraints to the _EditText_ places it in the horizontal center of the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Set heights of all elements to `MATCH_PARENT` and set the width of the `editText` to 0 for it to take up the remaining space.
If you don't want the buttons to be the same height as the `editText`, you can set all heights to `WRAP_CONTENT` and connect top and bottom of both buttons to top and bottom of the `editText`.

```kotlin
val constraintLayout = ConstraintLayout(context).apply {
    id = View.generateViewId()
    layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        MATCH_PARENT,
        MATCH_PARENT,
    )
}
val buttonA = ImageButton(context).apply {
    id = View.generateViewId()
    layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        WRAP_CONTENT,
        MATCH_PARENT,
    )
}
val buttonB = ImageButton(context).apply {
    id = View.generateViewId()
    layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        WRAP_CONTENT,
        MATCH_PARENT,
    )
}
val editText = EditText(context).apply {
    id = View.generateViewId()
    layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        0, //0 means match_constraints (take up the remaining space)
        MATCH_PARENT,
    )
}

...

set.connect(buttonA.id, ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START)

set.connect(editText.id, ConstraintSet.START, buttonA.id, ConstraintSet.END)
set.connect(editText.id, ConstraintSet.END, buttonB.id, ConstraintSet.START)

set.connect(buttonB.id, ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END)
```

Comment: I don't want to use chains, if I am not mistaking, my code should just work because the constraints are the same as in the XML files. That's why I am wondering: whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Your screenshot looks *exactly* like a chain. Maybe you have something different in mind? Do you want the buttons to have `wrap_content` width and the `EditText` to take up all of the space in between?

Comment: Hmm it may look like a chain but it isn't. EditText should take up the remaining space indeed. But this simple layout should be possible without using a chain right?

Comment: Oh, I understand. I changed the answer. Let me know if this solves your question.